# List items show / hide different and separate div with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, megamenu

as you can see from the question i'm not very good with jQuery and this type of coding.
I'm building a megamenu and one of the menu items should show a div like this picture: https://pasteboard.co/H2zzoDs.jpg 
As you can see in my fiddle https://codepen.io/byte37/pen/YYLmNq , i'm not able to show the corresponding Div of the li element i'm hovering on.
What i'm trying to achieve is that when I hover one of the list elements (li) i want to show the the corresponding Div.

```
<div class="cbi-main-menu">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="cbi-menu-sidebar">
              <h3 class="menu-item-prime">Menu</h3>
        <ul id="menu-left" class="no-style">
          <li><a id="lnk1" href="#" class="menu-item-1" >Link 1</a></li>
              <li><a id="lnk2" href="#" class="menu-item-2">Link 2</a></li>
              <li><a id="lnk3" href="#" class="menu-item-3">Link 3</a></li>
          <li><a id="lnk4" href="#" class="menu-item-4">Link 4</a></li>
          <li><a id="lnk5" href="#" class="menu-item-5">Link 5</a></li>
          <li><a id="lnk6" href="#" class="menu-item-6">Link 6</a></li>
          <li><a id="lnk7" href="#" class="menu-item-7">Link 7</a></li>
          <li><a id="lnk8" href="#" class="menu-item-8">Link 8</a></li>
          <li><a id="lnk9" href="#" class="menu-item-9">Link 9</a></li>
          <li><a id="lnk10" href="#" class="menu-item-10">Link 10</a></li>
          </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-1"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-1">Link1</div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-2">Link2</div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-3">Link3</div>
      <div class="link-show container-menu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-4">Link4</div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-5">Link5</div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-6">Link6</div>
      <div class="link-show container-menu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-7">Link7</div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-8">Link8</div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-9">Link9</div>
      <div class="link-show container-menu"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-10">Link10</div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('#menu-left li').hover(
        function() {
             $(this).closest('.container-menu').find('.link-show').show();
        },
        function() {
              $(this).closest('.container-menu').find('.link-show').hide();
    });
```

Extra question: since the content of the div i want show / hide, is mainly made by pictures, is there a way to load the content only when hovering on < li > element? Instead of loading everything and showing the contents only when hovering over the < li >'s?
Thanks!

Comment: One question per post, please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a data-menu for each li element which contains the id of the menu you want to show, something like this:

```html
<li data-menu="item-1"><a id="lnk1" href="#" class="menu-item-1" >Link 1</a></li>
```

Then you should add an id attribute to the div you want to show, like you already did for the first one:

```html
<div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-1">
    <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-1">Link1
</div>
```

Linking the two items this way, you can have a simple handler for hovering the li element, like:

```js
$('#menu-left li').hover(
  function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data("menu")).show();
  },
  function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data("menu")).hide();
  }
);
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for your answer, I've tried but i can't make it work: https://codepen.io/byte37/pen/JMZPyJ , i think it's because of the js code you wrote, the line  $("#" + $(this).data("menu")).show(); , istead of "menu" which selector should i use? Thanks

Comment: To make it work, I had to add jquery to your codepen. Try that maybe.

Comment: Thanks, but I've added it and it's still not working. Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: Mhmm, do you see this pen working?
https://codepen.io/ciamiz/pen/VydLPr

Comment: Jezz, thanks now i see it working. Strange it doesn't on mine. Anyways, just to know, data("menu") what's that menu and where does it take it from? Thanks for your patience.

Comment: The jQuery `data` method take an argument and returns the value of a `data-` attribute on that element. For instance, for an element like this:
`<div data-whatever="42"></div>`

You can get 42 calling `$("div").data("whatever")`

Comment: I know i shouldn't write thanks, but thanks guys, so much! :) Easy and clean explanation