# On mouseover <li> show Div but if mouseover another li hide div and show correct

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to finish with you guys this mega menu i'm building,
in another question i was helped showing and hiding a div while mouseover on `<li>`: [List items show / hide different and separate div with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48225368/list-items-show-hide-different-and-separate-div-with-jquery)
What I'm trying to achieve is that when i mouse over a li element i want to show a div correlated to it, but when i mouseover it must stay there (so the user can navigate into it), while if i mouseover on another li element it hides the previous one and shows its correlated div.
 
jQuery I'm using:

```
$('#menu-left li').hover(
  function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data("menu")).show();
  },
  function() {
    $("#" + $(this).data("menu")).hide();
  }
);
```

Html:

```
<div class="cbi-main-menu">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-3">
            <div class="cbi-menu-sidebar">
              <h3 class="menu-item-prime">Menu</h3>
        <ul id="menu-left" class="no-style">
          <li data-menu="item-1"><a id="lnk1" href="#" class="menu-item-1" >Link 1</a></li>
                <li data-menu="item-2"><a id="lnk2" href="#" class="menu-item-2">Link 2</a></li>
                <li data-menu="item-3"><a id="lnk3" href="#" class="menu-item-3">Link 3</a></li>
          <li data-menu="item-4"><a id="lnk4" href="#" class="menu-item-4">Link 4</a></li>
          <li data-menu="item-5"><a id="lnk5" href="#" class="menu-item-5">Link 5</a></li>
          <li data-menu="item-6"><a id="lnk6" href="#" class="menu-item-6">Link 6</a></li>
          <li data-menu="item-7"><a id="lnk7" href="#" class="menu-item-7">Link 7</a></li>
          <li data-menu="item-8"><a id="lnk8" href="#" class="menu-item-8">Link 8</a></li>
          <li data-menu="item-9"><a id="lnk9" href="#" class="menu-item-9">Link 9</a></li>
          <li data-menu="item-10"><a id="lnk10" href="#" class="menu-item-10">Link 10</a></li>
          </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-9">
            <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-1">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-1">Link1
      </div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-2">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-2">Link2
      </div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-3">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-3">Link3
      </div>
      <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-4">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-4">Link4
      </div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-5">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-5">Link5
      </div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-6">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-6">Link6
      </div>
      <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-7">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-7">Link7
      </div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-8">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-8">Link8
      </div>
            <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-9">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-9">Link9
      </div>
      <div class="link-show container-menu" id="item-10">
        <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" id="item-10">Link10
      </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this what you want? Instead bind the function to a hover event, you need to bind it to a mouseover event, thus the content won't disappear if you mouse out a "li", but only change if you entering into another "li".

```
$('#menu-left li').on("mouseover", function() {
     $("#" + $(this).data("menu")).show();
     $("#" + $(this).data("menu")).siblings().hide();
});
```

Comment: That's it! I've tried using siblings but was using it wrongly. Thanks

Comment: No problem. Glad it helps.

Comment: Why not.. `$("#" + $(this).data("menu")).show().siblings().hide();`?

Answer (score 0):

You have one little problem in your code. When using the jQuery selector $("#menu-left li") you should not forget that here you are trying to select multiple DOM li elements by single call. Therefore you have to loop through them in order to be able to apply your desired effect to each one of them.
If this is understood the working code should look like this:

```
$('#menu-left li').each(function(i,e){
    $(e).hover(
      function() {
        $("#" + $(this).data("menu")).show();
      },
      function() {
        $("#" + $(this).data("menu")).hide();
      }
   );
});
```

Also, don't forget to pre-set the 'display' CSS properties of your div elements to 'none' by default.